# Catching C# exceptions in IronPython without losing type information

Tags: c#, exception, ironpython

From my IronPython script, I call various C# methods, which may throw various types of exceptions.

With this C# code:

```
public class FooException : Exception {}
public class BarException : Exception {}

public class Test {
    public void foo() {
        throw new FooException("foo");
    }
    public void bar() {
        throw new BarException("bar");
    }
}
```

This IronPython code:

```
try:
    Test().foo()
except Exception as exc:
    print(repr(exc))
```

Will just print `Exception("foo")`. How do I determine whether the exception was a `FooException` or a `BarException`?

Comment: While you can do type determination after the fact, you could also simply catch the specific types, which is the recommended way of distinguishing exceptions: `except FooException as exc`. You can also `import System` and catch `System.Exception` (or `from System import Exception` if you know all exceptions in your code are CLR exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.
The IronPython exception object has a `clsException` member which contains the original C# exception object.

```
try:
    Test().foo()
except Exception as exc:
    print(isinstance(exc.clsException, FooException))
```